# Creating a library file for monitoring database connection reg

Tags: c#, .net

I need to create a library file which is to be placed with the bin folder of pre-compiled file.

So when ever any database connection is opened in that pre-compiled file the database connection must come to that library file and follow certain rules of mine and return it.

For example : Let us consider a web project which is deployed using publish website.Now I need to place my own `dll` in to that bin folder there by when ever the connection is opened in that project that connection string which is passing must read by my library file i.e. there by I can change some values in connection string(i.e database name etc....)
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Don't you have any ability to make changes to the main project? What is the bigger picture here, what are you trying to do? Maybe there is some other way to achieve your goal..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to place a .dll into a bin-folder for a project, then make that dll "pick up" any connection to a DB that is made inside the project, is that correct? Then you want to be able to manipulate the connection string that is used?

Is it possible for you to edit the main project too? I.e. make the main project call and make use of the .dll-file? If so, you could just encapsulate the whole connection-logic into the .dll. Otherwise, this sounds quite difficult.

If you can not change anything in the main project, you would at least need a wholly separate program to sit and "listen" for connections. You would then need some way to intercept the connections from your main project, but even then, getting the connection-string, manipulating it, and changing the way the main project uses it sounds... challenging.

What are you actually trying to do here anyway? I would recommend trying to either place all DB-connection stuff in the separate .dll, and using it as the library it is, OR look for some other form of config-solution to solve your problem (ie provide different connection-strings in a common config-file for use in different situations...?)

Comment: Ya ur right @kjartan for that only i am going for aop [aspect oreinted programming] concept ...........